# How to derive the size of vector inside a function? (the vector is passed by a pointer to its first element)

Tags: c++

I wonder, is there any approach to derive the size of a vector passed to a function by passing the address of its first element?

Here is the scenario:

```
void foo (double const *vec) {
    // Want the size of vec here in foo
}

int main () {
    std::vector<double> vec {1., 2., 3.};
    foo( &(vec[0]) );
}
```

**EDIT**

Thank you all for replying. I forgot to say that I want to know if there is any approach that can do the above job. After reading your answers, I think that there is no such method to do so. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You could add another argument to the function or pass the vector object in some form. The size data won't be magically accessible if you don't make it so.

Comment: Put the size into the pointed to element as one solution.

Comment: Classic [XY  Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Why do you need to know the number of elements inside of `foo`?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? If you need the `std::vector`, pass the `std::vector`.

Comment: The code will have to change to make this work. There are lots of different ways you could change the code to make this work, for example, passing the vector by reference instead. A global table the function could search for the vector in would be another way. Because no specific problem or requirement is stated in the question, it's hard to know which code changes would constitute an answer to the question and which code changes wouldn't.

Comment: The function does not get a vector; it gets a pointer to the first element of an array. It has no way of knowing that that array came from a vector. It could have been just a plain old array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. That information is usually stored in the `vector` class instance, which is not actually near the elements of the vector. In your case, `vec` is in `main`'s stack frame, while `vec[0]` is somewhere in the heap. The `vec` stack variable has pointers information about where the elements are, but not *vice versa*.

In fact, if you were to call `vec.pop_back()` in `main` before you called `foo`, all of the memory reachable through the parameter to `foo` would (probably) be identical, but the size would be different.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't passing a vector you are passing a double. You need to pass the vector and then you will have access to it's length. I would also prefer `const&` here.

```
void foo (std::vector<double> const& vec) {
    std::size_t length = vec.size()
}
```

You could also pass the length as a second parameter of your function. Like so.

```
void foo (double val, std::size_t length) {
    // do stuff here.
}

int main () {
    std::vector<double> vec{ 1., 2., 3. };
    foo(vec[0], vec.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a pointer to an element of the vector, you have erased any information associated with the vector itself. All you have is a pointer, in your case a pointer to a double. At that point, all you have to work with is a `double *`, and the only operations that will make sense are those that you can do on a pointer to double.